# Concerning the form of $C^3_{j,k}$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces

Is the Following Proof Correct?

**Theorem.** Suppose $C$ is an $n$-by-$n$ matrix and $1\leq j,k\leq n$. Show that the entry in
row $j$ , column $k$, of $C^3$ is 
$$\sum_{l=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}C_{j,l}C_{l,i}C_{i,k}$$
*Proof.* We may assume without loss of generality that $C$ is representative of some linear transformation $T$ on some *finite-dimensional* vector space $U$ having basis $u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_n\in U$.

Now let us compute $T^3u_k$ from definition we see that
$$T^3u_k = T(T(Tu_k))$$
moreover we know that $Tu_k = \sum_{i=1}^{n}C_{i,k}u_i$ substituting in above equation we have 
$$=T\left(T\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}C_{i,k}u_i\right)\right)=T\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}C_{i,k}Tu_i\right)
=T\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}C_{i,k}\left(\sum_{l=1}^{n}C_{l,i}u_l\right)\right)$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^{n}C_{i,k}\left(\sum_{l=1}^{n}C_{l,i}Tu_l\right) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}C_{i,k}\left(\sum_{l=1}^{n}C_{l,i}\left(\sum_{r=1}^{n}C_{r,l}u_r\right)\right)$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^{n}C_{i,k}\left(\sum_{r=1}^{n}\left(\sum_{l=1}^{n}C_{r,l}C_{l,i}\right)\right)$$
for purpose of convenience let $M_{r,i} = \sum_{l=1}^{n}C_{r,l}C_{l,i}$ therefore we have
$$=\sum_{i=1}^{n}C_{i,k}\left(\sum_{r=1}^{n}M_{r,i}u_r\right) = \sum_{r=1}^{n}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{n}M_{r,i}C_{i,k}\right)u_r$$
$$=\sum_{r=1}^{n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\sum_{l=1}^{n}C_{r,l}C_{l,i}\right)C_{i,k}\right)u_r
= \sum_{r=1}^{n}\left(\sum_{l=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}C_{r,l}C_{l,i}C_{i,k}\right)u_r$$
the right hand side of the last expression implies that $$C^3_{j,k} = \sum_{l=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}C_{j,l}C_{l,i}C_{i,k}$$

$\blacksquare$

Comment: Yes it's correct.

Comment: Your "assumption without loss of generality" could really be stated as something that you know. Normally when one says "assume without loss of generality" one is assuming something about which it is trivial to see that no generality is lost, i.e. one is restricting attention to a particular case when it is trivial to see that if the proposition holds in that case, then it holds in general. So I would phrase that line differently. You could say "The matrix $C$ is represents some linear transformation $T$ on some *finite-dimensional* vector space $U$ having basis $u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_n\in U."\quad$

Comment: @N.H. : $\qquad \uparrow \qquad$ I wouldn't let this point go unmentioned.